# Columns within uiOutput in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

In Shiny, I create a UI dynamically in the server element using `renderUI` and `tagList`, and then display it using `uiOutput`. It works, but I'd like to break up the contents of `uiOutput` into columns. How do I do that?

Here's the (slightly abbreviated) Dynamic UI example from the Shiny gallery. Note how `output$ui` contains a `tagList` that ends up displaying as one column, but I want it to display as two.

Note that I can't call `column` inside `renderUI`.

```
library(shiny)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$ui <- renderUI({
    if (is.null(input$input_type)) {return()}
    tagList(list(div("Want this to be left column"),
         switch(input$input_type,
           "slider" = sliderInput("dynamic", "Want this to be right column",
                                  min = 1, max = 20, value = 10),
           "text" = textInput("dynamic", "Want this to be right column",
                              value = "starting value"),
           "numeric" =  numericInput("dynamic", "Want this to be right column",
                                     value = 12),
           "checkbox" = checkboxInput("dynamic", "Want this to be right column",
                                      value = TRUE))))
  })
  output$input_type_text <- renderText({input$input_type})
  output$dynamic_value <- renderPrint({str(input$dynamic)})
})

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Dynamically generated user interface components"),
  wellPanel(selectInput("input_type", "Input type",
                        c("slider", "text", "numeric", "checkbox")
  )),
  wellPanel(uiOutput("ui")),
  wellPanel(
    tags$p("Input type:"),
    verbatimTextOutput("input_type_text"),
    tags$p("Dynamic input value:"),
    verbatimTextOutput("dynamic_value")
  )
))

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of wrapping `div` and a selected widget into `list` and then into `tagList` (you don't need them both - one of them suffice)

```
tagList(list(div("Want this to be left column"), switch(...) ...)
```

create `fluidRow` and add two columns - one with the `div` and the another with `switch`:

```
fluidRow(column(6, div("Want this to be left column")),
         column(6, switch(input$input_type,
                        "slider" = sliderInput("dynamic", "Want this to be right column",
                                               min = 1, max = 20, value = 10),
                        "text" = textInput("dynamic", "Want this to be right column",
                                           value = "starting value"),
                        "numeric" =  numericInput("dynamic", "Want this to be right column",
                                                  value = 12),
                        "checkbox" = checkboxInput("dynamic", "Want this to be right column",
                                                   value = TRUE)
                  )
          )
        )
```

---

**Full example:**

```
library(shiny)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$ui <- renderUI({
    if (is.null(input$input_type)) {return()}
    fluidRow(column(6, div("Want this to be left column")),
             column(6, switch(input$input_type,
                              "slider" = sliderInput("dynamic", "Want this to be right column",
                                                     min = 1, max = 20, value = 10),
                              "text" = textInput("dynamic", "Want this to be right column",
                                                 value = "starting value"),
                              "numeric" =  numericInput("dynamic", "Want this to be right column",
                                                        value = 12),
                              "checkbox" = checkboxInput("dynamic", "Want this to be right column",
                                                         value = TRUE)
             )
             )
    )
  })
  output$input_type_text <- renderText({input$input_type})
  output$dynamic_value <- renderPrint({str(input$dynamic)})
})

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Dynamically generated user interface components"),
  wellPanel(selectInput("input_type", "Input type",
                        c("slider", "text", "numeric", "checkbox")
  )),
  wellPanel(uiOutput("ui")),
  wellPanel(
    tags$p("Input type:"),
    verbatimTextOutput("input_type_text"),
    tags$p("Dynamic input value:"),
    verbatimTextOutput("dynamic_value")
  )
))

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```